# Java-Chat-App:: Analyse UserInput

Tags: java, string, vaadin

Im currently coding a Textchat with the Vaadin-Framework in Java.

Now my question: I want to avoid users spamming or posting useless texts, so i have some criteria to **filter my userinput (given as a String)** - How can i accomplish this?

1)Check for single Words longer than a defines WORD_CAP
2)Check for an overall INPUT_CAP
3)Check when there is no input
4)Check for certain words (swaerwords, maybe specific words, so i can generate another visualisation for certain words)

Goal: 
How can i accomplish this most efficiently in terms of time and work for the server (Wildfly 8) and what should i consider. Anyone experienced with this?

Also here the Code which is in my ClickListener, which the users click to send a message/input

```
String input = chatInputBox.getValue();

                if (input.length() <= MAX_CHAT_ZEICHEN_INPUT) {
                    if (!(input.length() == 0)) { 
                        if(analyseTooLongWords(input)) {

//More Code here
                }
            }
}
```

Method Analyse Words:

```
   private boolean analyseTooLongWords(String input) {

    String[] rows = input.split("\\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        String[] words = rows[i].split(" ");

        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (words[j].length() > MAX_WORD_LENGTH) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks for all answers in advance
Greetings DJ

Comment: "most efficiently" In terms of what? Space? Time? Readability? ...

Comment: You can avoid unnecessary object creation in `analyseTooLongWords` by using `String.indexOf` to find the next newline or space; you don't actually need the strings themselves, just how many characters are between the previous delimiter and current delimiter.

Comment: In terms of time and work for my server, i dont wanna use excessive performance for this task.

Comment: Time *and* work? Which is most important? Do you want something that takes very little time but lots of work, or lots of time but very little work? (You can't be optimal in terms of multiple criteria unless you can come up with some single-valued function of those parameters). I suspect what you are looking for is a *sufficient* solution, rather than "the most efficient" one. The question is then: in what respect is your current approach not sufficient for your requirements?

Comment: More in terms of work, i dont want that my server loses a lot of performance.

Comment: The Problem is that the runtime for a double loop is n^2, id like to reduce this if possible. Also i need to know how to search the text for words, so i know where in the text they are

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) <-- Donald Knuth

Answer (score 0):

I find it quite hard to believe that this is really worth optimizing; however, I provide a suggestion on the basis that you have done due diligence and determined that this code represents a genuine bottleneck in your system, and thus is worthy of micro-optimizing.

If you simply want to check the lengths of words (where "word" is defined as a consecutive block of characters delimited by either space or newline), you can simply iterate through the characters:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < input.length()) {
  while (i < input.length() && (input.charAt(i) == ' ' || input.charAt(i) == '\n')) {
    ++i;
  }
  int start = i;
  while (i < input.length() && (input.charAt(i) != ' ' && input.charAt(i) != '\n')) {
    ++i;
  }
  int wordLength = i - start;
  if (wordLength > MAX_WORD_LENGTH) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

This is O(n) because `i` makes a single pass through the characters in the input; no unnecessary objects are created.